# An alternative to FF-260PA-3057 motor

Tags: motor, alternatives

I have a rechargeable electric shaver which stopped working after a few years of use. If I charge it, it works for a few seconds, then stops.

I opened it and saw there is a short between the positive and negative pins of the motor it uses - [FF-260PA-3057](https://product.mabuchi-motor.com/detail.html?id=34). There is also a short between the positive and negative terminals of the battery, which I suppose are caused by the motor. It could also be the other way around, I'm not sure.

**Edit**: As Peter said, the battery could be the problem. This is the [model](http://www.yoycart.com/Product/39332808995/). Here I can buy only a few but the shipping costs are way too much. Can I just buy any battery that matches these specifications?

I intend to try and find out the problem when I get access to a soldering iron, but in the meantime I wanted to know if there exists an alternative to the motor. The reason I can't buy the original is because it is only sold in retail amounts - I can buy a minimum of 5000. Of course, if an alternative exists and the problem with the purchase remains, I'll give up on that.

Does anybody know of an alternative, **OR**, how do I effectively search for one myself?

For those that will probably ask why I just don't but a new shaver - I already have one, I'm doing this for fun, I want to try and revive and shaver.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "I saw there is a short..." - did you see a physical connection between the terminals, or did you measure continuity with a meter? or something else?

Comment: If it only works for a few seconds after charging the battery, the battery is probably dead.  (much more likely than a bad motor)

Comment: @PeterBennett Right, so I checked it with a multimeter and measured almost 0 ohms. You can see the traces in the circuit and there definitely shouldn't be a short between the plus and minus. About the battery - it's very possible. Problem with the battery is the same as the motor - sold in retail amounts. I'll add the model number to the question to see if an alternative could be found.

Comment: I think you mean "wholesale amounts", not "retail".  Anyway, a motor will have a very low DC resistance.  If the motor was faulty, I wouldn't expect it to run at all.

Comment: Wholesale it is then :) English is not my native language so I'm just glad you understood what I meant. About the resistance issue - does that mean that even if the shaver were working I would see what seems to be a short between the positive and negative terminals?

Comment: Measuring the resistance fo a motor will return surprisingly low values. Starting current (or stall current) can easily be 5-10x the operating current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FF-260PA-3057 specs say stall current is 6.75A at 2.4V. Using [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) to calculate the resistance gives 2.4V/6.75A = 0.36Ω. Your motor is probably OK, but the battery may be tired and needs replacing.

The cell you linked to is a 500mAh Nicad 5/7th AA size (same diameter as AA but ~30% shorter). Any cell that has similar specs should work. However this is a fairly rare industrial cell type, and Nicads are being phased out for environmental reasons, so they may be hard to find.

Your shaver must be an old model if it uses Nicads, so perhaps it is time to retire it.

Comment: Also, do you think it's possible to use other batteries with the same specs, but not Ni-Cd (if such exists)?

Comment: Yes, if you can find NiMH cells of similar _size_ (not capacity). I replaced the Nicads in my Philips shaver with AA Eneloops and it worked well. The built-in mains charger circuit would not properly charge NiMH, so I replaced it with a DC socket and used an external fast charger. This provided extra room for the batteries.

Comment: Why did it not charge well? I can't think of any reason for this.

Comment: NiMH has a lower Delta-V (voltage drop when fully charged) and also often does a 'false' peak within the first 10 minutes. A charger that is designed to fast charge Nicads only may either cut off too soon or not cut off at all when charging NiMH. If you use higher capacity cells the charging time will be longer and the Delta-V smaller. The charger may either not cut off because it doesn't detect the smaller change, or if it has a safety timer it may cut off early thinking that the battery _must_ be charged by now.